# Quick way to switch to other stack-exchange networks

Tags: feature-request

It would be really nice if there would be some dropdown or whatever where useres with connected stack-exchange accounts can switch to other stack-exchange sites.

Comment: yeah like this but maybe with direct access to the sites where you have connected accounts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, it is in the form of a dropdown in the top left of every site. There is a tab inside this dropdown for "all sites"

[image: Screenshot of switch site dropdown]

It will, as far as I can tell, order the list by the sites which you have visited most recently.

Comment: It's in order of your rep on those sites